# What causes a lock on an entity table in QuickBooks Online API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to optimize my application to perform at maximum speed. I intended on having two threads each executing a batch request of sales receipts additions. I also intended on having two parallel threads each with a batch request of customer additions. I was wondering whether this is possible or would the API lock the sales receipt/customer table in QuickBooks thus only allowing one thread to perform.

From my research I know that there a three types of entities (Name list, transaction and supporting entities). So what are the causes of locks on these entities, ie what scenario's will cause a lock? Is there any documentation on this matter I couldn't seem to find any?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock is applicable for Name entities(Vendor, Customer and Employee ). While creating a new name entity, service ensures that an unique name is getting inserted in cloud. So, it puts a lock across all names of these 3 entities.

You can try this scenario using a decent payload.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PropertyConfigurator
            .configure("log4j.properties");
    Config.setProperty(Config.SERIALIZATION_REQUEST_FORMAT, "xml");
    Config.setProperty(Config.SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE_FORMAT, "xml");

    final Context platformContext = getPlatformContext("QBO");  
    final QBOV3ProdTest qbov3ProdTest = new QBOV3ProdTest(platformContext);

    Thread customerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                qbov3ProdTest.addCustomer();
            }
        }
    });
    customerThread.start();

    Thread vendorThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                qbov3ProdTest.addVendor();
            }
        }
    });
    vendorThread.start();

}

private void addCustomer() {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setDisplayName("TestCustomer-" + staticCount++);
    try {
        this.service.add(customer);
    } catch (FMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addVendor() {
    Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
    vendor.setDisplayName("TestVendor-" + staticCount++);
    try {
        this.service.add(vendor);
    } catch (FMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Service doesn't return a proper response. Wherever it fails, service returns 401. Please let me know if you can reproduce this behaviour while trying this use-case in your test QBO account.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Manas thanks for your response. What if both threads were doing addCustomer? would there still be a lock on the customer name entity? I understand that parallel processing on different name entities is not possible due to the lock, but what about if the name entities on multiple threads are the same (eg 2 threads with add customer on one thread and add customer on the second thread)? would this work?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the behaviour and report the results to you as soon as possible. When you have time can you please respond to above comment thank you very much you have been very helpful.

Comment: Hi Manas, I have some interesting information for you. I am using the .NET devkit. I tried the code you provided but converted it to .NET. I did a batch request of vendors on one thread and a batch of customers on another. Errors and conflicts occured. Some, but not all customers added, and some but not all vendors added. I also got this error in some parts of the logs: "Validation Error: You can only add or edit one name at a time.  Please try again". Also two threads with customer additions causes visual studio to crash as does two threads with sales receipts additions.

Comment: Two threads, one with customer additions and one with sales receipts additions worked fine.

Comment: You'll get similar behaviour while using a java devkit. Some objects will be added and some will fail. Client doesn't matter in these API calls. I'll try to share more details related to this locking. If you create customer and dependent transactions(invoice, salesreceipt) then that should not cause any problem.

Comment: Yes please when you have time share more info on the locking feature. Also unfortunately Visual studio reports an error when there are two threads accessing the same entity via batch requests (eg customer, customer or sales receipt, sales receipt) however one thread sometimes executes successfully. It would be extremely fast if for example two threads with batch requests of sales receipts additions was compatible with the API. I guess it's still ok because one batch request followed by another on the same thread is reasonably fast anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We had followed up with dev team. Nimisha has shared the update which we got from them. We'll update all these info(entity specific behaviour) in IPP's docs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a DB locking rule but because of the way we are saving data to our cache for Names lists.

We do not allow users to update these entities in a multi-threaded manner:

Account,
Department,
Item,
Class,
Customer,
Employee,
Vendor,
PaymentMethod,
Terms.

The above has been confirmed by our engineering team.